# php form is not submitting

Tags: php, forms

```
<form action="log.php" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
              &nbsp;
            </div><!-- /.col -->
            <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" value="Sign In" />
              <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>-->
            </div><!-- /.col -->
          </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: your question not clear, try to clarify

Comment: the form looks fine - have you got the path to the action correct?

Comment: what is your error message?

Comment: the form is submitting for me: https://jsfiddle.net/6x17wpwj/

Comment: It is submitting but not log.php. it is submitting to login.php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'log.php' exists, I have written this to help you confirm that the form has been submitted.

Put the following stuff into your 'log.php' file:

```
echo $_POST['email'];  //should diplay the email id entered in the form
echo $_POST['password']; //should display the password entered
```

Before adding the above code, make sure that your `log.php` is of the following structure:

```
<html>
<body>
<!--Something that you already have-->
<?php
//all the code including what I have mentioned above.
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The email id and password entered in the form will be displayed. This means that the form has been submitted.

If it doesn't display, please check if `log.php` is in the same directory where the html form is placed.